# Wrong activity is launchnung when app is reloading

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-lifecycle

Whenever my app crashes and my phone asks me if I want to reload it and I say yes, the wrong activity is launching.

Here's my manifest. How should I deal with it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.applicationpro">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="AuthentifierPro"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory, android:label">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.CameraActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.CameraCompPicComp2Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.CameraComp2Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SearchActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.Historic2Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.FicheActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.darsh.multipleimageselect.activities.AlbumSelectActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MultipleImageSelectTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider2"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.DelayChoiceActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ProfilActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.HistoricActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.BrandChoiceActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.authentifier.com"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.AlarmReceiver"
            android:process=":remote" />

        <service
            android:name=".service.NotificationService"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

BrandChoiceActivity is loading. But when I'm starting my app it should be LoginActivity. It works the first time but not when my app is crashing.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm pretty sure it would be a great way to deal with it. I meant how do you deal with the fact that my app is reloading on the wrong activity. Thank you.

Comment: It's probably the last activity in the stack that loads. I don't understand why you're more concerned about which activity shows after a crash and not the crash itself.

Comment: Because if someone uses my app and if it is not bug-free, if he decides to reload it, it will get this application first. Also, I don't think it is pretty safe to "let it be". I'm gonna dig this sentence "Probably the last activity in the stack that loads". Thank you for this lead!

Comment: And "of course" I'm also interested by the crash itself. I just don't believe I should limit myself to the crash :)

Comment: Chances are the two things are connected, hence us trying to point you towards the first step you should consider, which is to see why your app is crashing and fix it. Then just pass a null reference somewhere to force crash your app and see if you get the same behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and respect!

Comment: What is the crash in the first place? It might help someone understand your problem better and come up with a more foolproof solution. Try editing your question by adding your logcat from the crash

Answer (score 1):

@NikosHidalgo I followed your lead with *It's probably the last activity in the stack that loads.* and it was the solution to my issue. BCActivity was not "finished" before calling another activity. So when my app was crashing, it was calling the only activity still in stack: BrandChoiceActivity. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code but my suggestion is simple check your code first if you are saving data while login and redirected to BrandChoiceActivity if data is already stored somewhere like SharedPref.

Comment: I don't have this situation. Sharing my whole code would be complicated. I go through LoginActivity to MainActivity. I have 10 more activities, including BCActivity. Do you see anything wrong in my Manifest? It would be a lead to pursue if you do :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your Login Activity?
It might be opening BrandChoiceActivity activity. To check you should print logs in LoginActivity onCreate and BrandsActivity if its showing LoginActivity logs then it is going through it.

Comment: I checked and there is no mention to BCActivity into LoginActivity. The only two moments BCActivity is called is when clicking on a button, defined into MainActivity and through my menu. My menu is not implemented into LoginActivity.

Comment: But is it opening LoginActivity? Did you check its log?

Comment: Well, it's not crashing anymore but the wrong activity is still called. I'm gonna update my question with some more informations.

Answer (score -1):

```
    @SuppressLint("Registered")
   class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
   public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(
            this::handleUncaughtException);}

private void handleUncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you bring some background to your solution please? I don't really get it.

Comment: @Lena this makes sure that whenever your app crashes with an exception that you haven't foreseen, it clears the stack of activities and reloads with your MainActivity in focus.

Comment: It is the best way to approach crashes.